# Writing a simple web crawler that interacts with the browser (Java)

Tags: java, browser, web-crawler, bots, interaction

I need to create an automated process (preferably using Java) that will:

1. Open browser with specific url.
2. Login, using the username and password specified.
3. Follow one of the links on the page.
4. Refresh the browser.
5. Log out.

This is basically done to gather some statistics for analysis. Every time a user follows the link a bunch of data is generated for this particular user and saved in database. The thing I need to do is, using around 10 fake users, ping the page every 5-15 min.

Can you tink about simple way of doing that? There has to be an alternative to endless login-refresh-logout manual process...

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=web+crawler+java

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." 
Check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @VinayakKaniyarakkal thanks for your input. Indeed I asked an off-topic question and I got a perfect answer which allowed me to solve the problem I had. I hope I didn't attract too much spam while doing it. Can you suggest a Stack Overflow alternative that is more suited for these types of questions?

Comment: @JurekKozyra softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Thanks ;) It works really well as a browser plugin.

On the other hand I'm struggling with getting the generated code work in my Java program (for instance I want to wait X sec before refreshing the page - easier to do in code than in browser plugin). Setting up Selenium RC can be painfull...

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) if you want

1. FAST
2. SIMPLE

java based web interaction/crawling.

**For example:** here is some simple code showing a bunch of output and an example of accessing all IMG elements of the loaded page.

```
public class HtmlUnitTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());

    for (HtmlElement node : page.getHtmlElementDescendants()) {
      if (node.getTagName().toUpperCase().equals("IMG")) {
        System.out.println("NAME: " + node.getTagName());
        System.out.println("WIDTH:" + node.getAttribute("width"));
        System.out.println("HEIGHT:" + node.getAttribute("height"));
        System.out.println("TEXT: " + node.asText());
        System.out.println("XMl: " + node.asXml());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example #2** Accessing named input fields and entering data/clicking:

```
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");

HtmlElement inputField = page.getElementByName("q");
inputField.type("Example input");

HtmlElement btnG = page.getElementByName("btnG");
Page secondPage = btnG.click();

if (secondPage instanceof HtmlPage) {
  System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
  System.out.println(((HtmlPage)secondPage).getTitleText());
}
```

**NB:** You can use page.refresh() on any Page object.

Comment: Yes, Htmlunit is the best choice for writing java crawlers ... unless the user wants to load test a web site, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Edited answer and added example of inputing data and clicking on a button. I also provided details on how to refresh the browser. I believe that the metrics are being captured by the web application/server and that j3ny is only seeking to provide mock users at a specified frequency. HtmlUnit seems like a perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Java, but Javascript. You could do something like:

```
window.location = "<url>"
document.getElementById("username").value = "<email>";    
document.getElementById("password").value = "<password>";

document.getElementById("login_box_button").click();
```

...

etc

With this kind of structure you can easily cover 1-3. Throw in some for loops for page refreshes and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Jakarta JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)